# Share a link on FaceBook without creating a facebook app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

From my iPhone app I would like to share a link on Facebook. I know that this can be done by creating an app in the facebook and use the id/key of that Facebook app.

Is there any other way for sharing a link in FB, like the AddThis library for webapps. So that I neednot create an app in the facebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AddThis has iOS Sdk now : http://www.addthis.com/help/ios-overview

Comment: Looking through the forums there it seems less-than-stellar on updates. Have a look at http://getsharekit.com/ as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. AFAIK, the best & easiest way to do this is w a Facebook app. User authentication (through a Facebook app) is required in order to post anything to a wall; anonymous wall posts are not allowed. It's really easy to create a Facebook app. Then, check out the facebook-ios-sdk.

Comment: any thing similar to addthis available for iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot have anonymous wall posts to facebook, so I would recommend using the sdk, if you only need to post to walls, take a look at www.getsharekit.com which will make this trivial to do

Comment: But there are web apps which uses AddThis api, by which we can post links/comments etc on facebook without creating an app in FB. Isn't there any similar techniques we can use in iPhone SDK?